# How to search by geocode with twitter?

Tags: node.js, twitter, geocoding

So in my node.js code I have the following parameters:

```
var params = {
q: 'since:2017-04-04', // REQUIRED //goes by year-month-date
geocode: '33.743450 -84.393138 10mi',
result_type: 'recent',
count:'100',
lang*: 'en'
}
```

If I do not have geocode, it works fine. If however, I do have the geocode then it returns nothing at all. I was following the API instructions so I am 100% that it is actually a valid parameter. Thus, my question, how to use the geocode parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [geo/search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/geo/search) endpoint.

Comment: So the geocode tag won't work at all even though it mentioned in the search/tweets portion of the API?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I am sure it will as it is part of twitter's api.

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but I was came across this problem today and thought I would add the answer.

You need to remove the spaces and format the geocode key pair like this:

```
var params = {
q: 'since:2017-04-04', // REQUIRED //goes by year-month-date
geocode: '33.743450,-84.393138,10mi',
result_type: 'recent',
count:'100',
lang*: 'en'
}
```